# Should you always unpersist earlier cached rdds after you cache an rdd that appears later in the same lineage graph?

Tags: apache-spark, caching, amazon-s3

I have an rdd that I cache after loading data from s3, since I don't want to have to re-pull from s3 if I lose an executor. I then make a bunch of transformations on that rdd, and then cache again.

At this point, is there any reason to leave the first cached rdd in the cache? Will all later stages just pull from the more recently cached transformation if I don't use the earlier rdd again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to have to re-pull from s3 if I lose an executor.

Default `caching` variants don't protect you from executor loss. Spark provides replicated `cache` options (`MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2`, `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2`, `DISK_ONLY_2`) which add some protection in case of node failure, but there more expensive than non-replicated variants.

> is there any reason to leave the first cached rdd in the cache?

If the second one has been materialized then there is no reason to keep the first one, but LRU cleaner should be able to do handle this case without your help, if it is necessary.